# white Window in Qt creator

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qml, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 4.6.2 in window 7.

when I try to choose design tag in Qt Creator it shows nothing but a white screen and nothing else

[image]

and when I try to run a simple qml code in output its again showing a white screen with visual c++ runtime error.
please help me for the same.

Comment: What exactly error did you get? Is that a newly installed QtCreator or problem appeared as the result of any action? The more accurately you describe the problem, the more likely you are to get an answer here.

Comment: Is it a clean (QtQuick)-project or is there anything already in the main.qml?

Comment: No there is window programming in main.qml.it gets run when i run it and shows whatever i had coded but the problem arrives when i try to GUI to design the page

Comment: @folibis there is no error showing but whenever I try to use GUI for page designing it shows nothing but a white screen.but its options can be seen by hovering the mouse on the screen.

Comment: My guess is, that you have stuff in the file, that the designer can not handle. Only a reduced set of components is compatible with the designer. This however is not possible to verify without the code. Please show a minimal example that reproduces your problem. (#code, #minimal, #complete, #verifiable)

Answer (score 1):

That may be because the renderer fails on your machine. That's corroborated by the "options being visible when you hover with the mouse above the white screen". Most likely, the graphics card driver that you have is buggy and outdated.

A workaround is to use a different renderer backend and/or a different OpenGL implementation. You can choose from the following options of environmental variable settings - they are all exclusive, i.e. you can only choose one at a time. They cannot be mixed. Note that `""` means an empty string, i.e. the variable should be defined but empty.

1. `QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM=d3d11`, `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=""` - OpenGL renderer running on top of Direct3D 11
2. `QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM=d3d9`, `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=""` - OpenGL renderer running on top of Direct3D 9
3. `QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM=warp`, `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=""` - OpenGL renderer running on top of a software Direct3D 11 rasterizer
4. `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=d3d12` - Direct3D 12 renderer (experimental, doesn't use OpenGL)
5. `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=software` - a software renderer backend, with no shader support

But also: try updating the graphics card driver (after backing up your system - I mean it!), or try replacing with a more modern card that is still supported in Windows 7 (it doesn't have to be anything expensive at all). Perhaps it could be a bug in ANGLE, an OpenGL implementation that runs on top of DirectX, and is used by Qt on Windows because OpenGL support on Windows is even worse than DirectX support. But short of hacking on ANGLE, the simplest bet for you is to try the above suggestions.